# Login and authentication functionality in Django REST API and React Native

Tags: python, django, react-native, software-design

One of my projects I have developed backend API using `Django REST Framework` and mobile app using `React Native`. I have done the following things:

1. When the users log in I store their username in local (mobile) database.
2. When users `post` data I send the username to server reading from local database along with the `POST` data.
3. I check whether the user is logged in or not using the username and then process the request.

My question is: am I doing it in the right way? If no then what are the right procedures to do this kind of authentication checking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you authenticating your users? It sounds like your using sessions authentication which is fine as long as both ends are on the same doamin. Then you just use the request.user object as you normal would in a non-api setting. I would recommend using Django-rest-framework-Jwt https://github.com/GetBlimp/django-rest-framework-jwt Json Web Tokens do not require you to store a bunch of information in sessions on your server keeping things faster.

Here is a good example of implementing jwt if your interested https://www.techiediaries.com/django-rest-framework-jwt-tutorial/